# MongoDB (Mongoose) with Node.js connection errors - Looking for insight

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to node.js and mongoDB Atlas. I am having an issue connecting to Mongo Atlas using the Node.js version 3.0 or later connection string.

```
const MongoDB = 'mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@cluster0-nnezr.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
```

When I use this connection string I get the following error -

MongoDB connection error: Error: querySrv ETIMEOUT _mongodb._tcp.cluster0-nnezr.mongodb.net
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:203:19) {
  errno: undefined,
  code: 'ETIMEOUT',
  syscall: 'querySrv',
  hostname: '_mongodb._tcp.cluster0-nnezr.mongodb.net'
}
(node:38809) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: querySrv ETIMEOUT _mongodb._tcp.cluster0-nnezr.mongodb.net
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:203:19)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:38809) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside ofan async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:38809) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections thatare not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

I have found a workaround using the previous connection string for node.js version 2.2.12 -

```
mongodb://<user>:<password>@cluster0-shard-00-00-nnezr.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-nnezr.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-nnezr.mongodb.net:27017/<dbname>?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

When connecting I have to add {useUnifiedTopology: true}

```
mongoose.connect(mongoDB, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
```

Can anyone give me a little insight on what im doing wrong with the new connection string?

Thanks!

Comment: are you using an .env file?
try writing
 { useNewUrlParser: true, useFindAndModify: false, useUnifiedTopology: true }

Comment: No not using a .env file. Tried adding {useFindAndModify: false} but still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

have write user, password and maybe also database ,

```
   const MongoDB = 'mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@cluster0-nnezr.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
```

**user = your mongodb user name**

**password = your mongodb password**

**dbname  = Database name**

and don't forget to create a new user in MongoDB atlas.

Comment: this goes without saying that you did that right? XD

Comment: thought he missed those fields.

Comment: Yes, this is not the problem =D

Comment: I did not include my username and password or DB name in the question intentionally.

Comment: yeah though so XD
show us the code because as it is i cant see a problem

Comment: yah i thought that would be the problem , code would be more helpful.